# Issue displaying ByteArray image from servlet in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer

In my JSP I have some code that gets a byte array from a jsp:

```
photo.innerHTML = "<img src='" + "<%=getPictureUrl%>" + "&amp;pidm=" + x[i].getAttribute("pidm") + "'></img>";
```

with the unique ID of the user tacked on as a url parameter. On the java side, I get the image and convert it to a byte array.

```
                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                System.out.print("getInputStream ");

                 if (is instanceof ByteArrayInputStream) {
                  size = is.available();
                  buf = new byte[size];
                  len = is.read(buf, 0, size);
                } 
                else {
                  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                  buf = new byte[size];
                  while ((len = is.read(buf, 0, size)) != -1)
                    bos.write(buf, 0, len);
                  buf = bos.toByteArray();
                }

                 o.write(buf);                       
                 o.flush();
                 o.close();
```

This works well in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE, a black box with an "x" is displayed, like the browser can't find the image. Is there something special that needs to be done in IE to fix this? I'm not seeing any errors in the web console.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to set content type of my response:

```
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
```